# nodejs make a GET call to an https site

Tags: node.js, http, https, proxy

i am using nodejs v0.10.28 on ubuntu 12LTS,
am trying to make a request to https enable site behind a web proxy using this test code:

```
 var http = require("http");

    var options = {
        host: "mycompany.proxy.host",
        port: 8088,
        //host: "https://login.launchpad.net",
        //port: 443,
        //path: "/",
        headers: {
           Host: "login.launchpad.net"
        }
     };
     http.get(options, function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        res.pipe(process.stdout);
     }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
     });
```

but am not sure what are the correct option params to use to make a successful HTTP GET

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: You may find it easier to use request - https://github.com/mikeal/request - which is a wrapper around Node’s HTTP/HTTPS functionality, and it has proxy support.

Comment: ..thanks this tip about request let me closer to the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using node [`https`](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) instead of `http` module for making https requests. Otherwise the server will most likely reset your connection, and an ECONNRESET error will be caught by the error handler.